# How to get counts per each partition in the values ranging 0-10, 10-20,... 90-100

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a data that is in the range of 1-100. I want to get count of this data per the following ranges. Let's say I have this data: `[17, 30, 62 65, 92, 95, 98]`. I want to obtain this:

```
00-10: 0
11-20: 1
21-30: 1
31-40: 0
41:50: 0
51:60: 0
61:70: 2
71:80: 0
81:90: 0
91:100: 3
```

I wonder if there is pandas/numpy/spicy function to achieve this fast. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
bins = np.arange(0,110,10)
s = pd.Series([17, 30, 62, 65, 92, 95, 98])
s1 = pd.cut(s, bins=bins)
print (s1.value_counts(sort=False))
(0, 10]      0
(10, 20]     1
(20, 30]     1
(30, 40]     0
(40, 50]     0
(50, 60]     0
(60, 70]     2
(70, 80]     0
(80, 90]     0
(90, 100]    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! When I use your code, for some reason, some values are not included in the bins. Normally, I have 136 records, after I run your code, I get around 113 (when summing the counts). Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think you need parameter `include_lowest=True` - `s1 = pd.cut(s, bins=bins, include_lowest=True)` for count `0` values.

Comment: this helped! but still missing 5 values.

Comment: Or maybe there is problem some values are less as `0` or higher as `100`

Comment: try change bins to `bins =  [-np.inf] + np.arange(0,110,10).tolist() + [np.inf]` and then get values out of range `0-100`

Comment: still the same, have no idea why.

Comment: ok, what are values? Can you add all values to comment or to question?

Comment: thanks for the help dude, there are some `None` values, that was the reason. Thanks again!

Comment: super, I test many values but not None. Thank you for accepting!

Answer (score 5):

This is just histogramming, so `np.histogram(data, np.arange(0,101,10))[0]`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) and putting that output in [`numpy.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).

Example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([9, 17, 30, 62, 65, 92, 95, 98])

bins = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
inds = np.digitize(a, bins) - 1

counts  = np.bincount(inds)
for r, count in zip(bins, counts):
    print((r, r+10), count)
```

This returns the desired result. Numpy digitize basically tells you where your number should be inserted in a monotonically increasing or decreasing array. If you then bincount that you get the counts per partition. Because `np.digitize` returns `i` such that `bins[i-1] <= x < bins[i]` you need to subtract one to get the first value for the first bin (bin 0).

Comment: You should elaborate and show an example and this could be a very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

non-numpy solution, maybe it'll look lame... Using `collections.Counter` and rounding:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [ 10,11,17, 30, 62, 65, 92, 95, 98,100]

# directly count using a generator comprehension instead of a loop
c = Counter(((i-1)//10)*10 for i in a)


for i in range(0,((max(a)+1)*10)//10,10):
    print("{}-{}: {}".format(i+1,i+10,c[i] if i in c else 0))
```

Basically counting each occurrence, and then print all the values or 0 if not in dictionary: note it's not counting 0 or negative numbers.

result (changed the input data & boundaries by adding 1 because it was ambiguous):

```
1-10: 1
11-20: 2
21-30: 1
31-40: 0
41-50: 0
51-60: 0
61-70: 2
71-80: 0
81-90: 0
91-100: 4
101-110: 0
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate to count with `Counter`.  `Counter(a)` will do.

Comment: @piRSquared done, thanks for the suggestion, I tend to forget that nice feature.

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve this with in-built `bisect` module as:

```
from bisect import bisect

my_list = [17, 30, 62, 65, 92, 95, 98]  # sort it if not already sorted
my_interval = list(range(0, 101, 10))

new_list = [((i+1, j), len(my_list[bisect(my_list, i+1):bisect(my_list, j)])) \
    for i, j in zip(my_interval, my_interval[1:])]
```

The final value hold be new_list will be:

```
[((0, 10), 0), ((10, 20), 1), ((20, 30), 1), ((30, 40), 0), ((40, 50), 0), ((50, 60), 0), ((60, 70), 2), ((70, 80), 0), ((80, 90), 0), ((90, 100), 3)]
```

In order to print the values in desired format, you do:

```
for (i, j), val in new_list:
    print '{}-{}: {}'.format(i, j, val)
```

which will print:

```
1-10: 0
11-20: 1
21-30: 1
31-40: 0
41-50: 0
51-60: 0
61-70: 2
71-80: 0
81-90: 0
91-100: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
# use np.where or np.nonzero for indices and np.logical_and to set alpha/omega
a = np.array([17, 30, 62, 65, 92, 95, 98])

for n in range(0,100,10):
  b = a[np.where(np.logical_and(a>=n, a<=n+10))]
  c = a[np.nonzero(np.logical_and(a>=n, a<=n+10))]
  print ((n, n+10), len(b), len(c), b, c)

(0, 10) 0 0 [] []
(10, 20) 1 1 [17] [17]
(20, 30) 1 1 [30] [30]
(30, 40) 1 1 [30] [30]
(40, 50) 0 0 [] []
(50, 60) 0 0 [] []
(60, 70) 2 2 [62 65] [62 65]
(70, 80) 0 0 [] []
(80, 90) 0 0 [] []
(90, 100) 3 3 [92 95 98] [92 95 98]
```